# Graphview not showing all x axis values

Tags: android, graph, android-graphview

See picture below, trying to figure out why they it is skipping the '1', '3', and so forth.

[image: Bar Graph Example]

Where i set the series and graph:

```
DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[rankList.size()]; // declare an array of DataPoint objects with the same size as your list

        for (int i = 0; i < rankList.size(); i++) {

            dataPoints[i] = new DataPoint(i, Double.parseDouble(rankList.get(i))); // not sure but I think the second argument should be of type double
        }

        BarGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new BarGraphSeries<DataPoint>(dataPoints); // This one should be obvious right? :)

        series2.setAnimated(true);
        series2.setTitle("Random Curve 1");
        series2.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        series2.setSpacing(30);

        series2.setDataWidth(1);

        graph2.getViewport().setMinX(-1);
        graph2.getViewport().setMaxX(12);

        graph2.addSeries(series2);
```

The right info is being plotted, but i've tried a bunch of stuff from the docs and get get it to work.

Comment: Updated, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I misunderstood your question...

This will help:

```
yourGraph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(numberOfBars);
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually shows all bars. You've set  `series2.setSpacing(30);`.
Instead do `series2.setSpacing(0);`.